# Trying to initialize two matrices Row and Col, at the same time, using a 3rd matrix

Tags: java, arrays

Matrix row is the sum of all the numbers if one row, and Matrix col is the sm of all numbers in one col
if we have this matix  m:

```
[1 2 3 4]
[3 4 5 1]
[1 2 0 1]
```

our Matrix row is:

```
[1 3 6 10]
[3 7 12 13]
[1 3 3 4]
```

and our Matrix col is:

```
[1 2 3 4]
[4 6 8 5]
[5 8 8 6]
```

I am writing a method to fill in two NxM matrices at the same time. the matrix row should be filled by its row and matrix col should be filled in its columns.

this is my code:

```
Row[0][0] = m[0][0]
Col[0][0] = m[0][0]
for(int i = 0; i < nrRow; i++){
  for(int j = 0; i < nrRow; j++){
     Row[i][j] = Row[i][j]+m[i][j]
  }
}
```

but I dont know how to fill in the Col matrix.
the entire operation should be done on O(n^2).

Comment: How is last row in colMatrix is `5 8 0 6`? Shouldn't it be `5 8 8 6`?

Comment: u r right, i corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For `colMatrix`, for every index `[i, j]`, you have to fill it up with `m[i][j] + colMatrix[i][j - 1]`. Where `m` is the original matrix, and `colMatrix` is the new one, which you are filling up. Now, you have to consider the case when `j == 0` separately, in which case, you woul dhave `colMatrix[i][j] = m[i][j]`
2. Similarly for `rowMatrix`, for every index `[i, j]`, the value will be `m[i][j] + rowMatrix[i - 1][j]`. And for `i == 0`, you would have `rowMatrix[i][j] = m[i][j]`.

Here's the code:

```
    int[][] m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5, 1}, {1, 2, 0, 1}};

    int[][] rowMatrix = new int[m.length][m[0].length];
    int[][] colMatrix = new int[m.length][m[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {

            if (j == 0) rowMatrix[i][j] = m[i][j]; 
            else        rowMatrix[i][j] = m[i][j] + rowMatrix[i][j - 1];

            if (i == 0) colMatrix[i][j] = m[i][j];
            else        colMatrix[i][j] = m[i][j] + colMatrix[i - 1][j];

        }
    }
```

Comment: @S.N Yes, unless the arrays are not zagged.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that nrRow is number of rows(3 for this example) and nrCol is number of columns (4 for this example):

```
//Rows
for(int i = 0; i < nrRow; i++){

  Row[i][0] = m[i][0];      

  for(int j = 0; j < nrCol - 1; j++){

     Row[i][j + 1] = Row[i][j] + m[i][j + 1];

  }
}

//Columns
for(int i = 0; i < nrCol; i++){

  Col[0][i] = m[0][i]; 

  for(int j = 0; j < nrRow - 1; j++){

     Col[j + 1][i] = Col[j][i] + m[j + 1][i];

  }
}
```

Comment: is this in O(n^2), the first one for row is definite O(n^2) and the second one for col as well. so if we have O(n^2) + O(n^2) does i mean the time is O(n^2)?? is this gonna work with row>10000 and col>10000??

Comment: @S.N Yes. This is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @S.N Yes. Since both of for loops have O(n^2) complexity, practically, they will be O(2*n^2) but since 2 does not depend on x, you can neglect it. So it can be considered as O(n^2) algorithm.